# Hibernate delete parent

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany, bidirectional-relation

When I want to delete a parent in Hibernate, if there is child is there a mechanism that throws an exception?

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
private Category category;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
```

not delete category, if the product belongs to the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would Hibernate throw an exception on category delete that contains products? You're asking Hibernate to do it by defining `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`.

If you don't want a category to be deleted when it contains some products you need to make sure of it by yourself:

```
if (category.containsProducts()) {
    throw new Exception();
}
categoryRepository.delete(category);
```